# Reading from file, then using data as a list

Tags: list, haskell, io

So I have a text file called testData which contains the following data:

```
[("Blade Runner","Ridley Scott",1982,[("Amy",6),("Bill",9),("Ian",7),("Kevin",9), 
("Emma",4),("Sam",5),("Megan",4)]),
("The Fly","David Cronenberg",1986,[("Megan",4),("Fred",7),("Chris",5),("Ian",0),("Amy",5)]),
("Psycho","Alfred Hitchcock",1960,[("Bill",4),("Jo",4),("Garry",8),("Kevin",7),
("Olga",8),("Liz",10),("Ian",9)]),
("Body Of Lies","Ridley Scott",2008,[("Sam",3),("Neal",7),("Kevin",2),("Chris",5),   ("Olga",6)]),
("Avatar","James Cameron",2009,[("Olga",2),("Wally",8),("Megan",9),("Tim",5),("Zoe",8),("Emma",3)]),
("Titanic","James Cameron",1997,[("Zoe",7), ("Amy",2), ("Emma",5), ("Heidi",3), ("Jo",8), ("Megan",5), ("Olga",7), ("Tim",10)]),
("The Departed","Martin Scorsese",2006,[("Heidi",2), ("Jo",8), ("Megan",5), ("Tim",2), ("Fred",5)]),
("Aliens","Ridley Scott",1986,[("Fred",8), ("Dave",6), ("Amy",10), ("Bill",7), ("Wally",2), ("Zoe",5)]),
("Prometheus","Ridley Scott",2012,[("Garry",3), ("Chris",4), ("Emma",5), ("Bill",1), ("Dave",3)]),
("E.T. The Extra-Terrestrial","Steven Spielberg",1982,[("Ian",7), ("Amy",2), ("Emma",7), ("Sam",8), ("Wally",5), ("Zoe",6)]),
("The Birds","Alfred Hitchcock",1963,[("Garry",7), ("Kevin",9), ("Olga",4), ("Tim",7), ("Wally",3)]),
("Goodfellas","Martin Scorsese",1990,[("Emma",7), ("Sam",9), ("Wally",5), ("Dave",3)]),
("The Shawshank Redemption","Frank Darabont",1994,[("Jo",8), ("Sam",10), ("Zoe",3), ("Dave",7), ("Emma",3), ("Garry",10), ("Kevin",7)]),
("Gladiator","Ridley Scott",2000,[("Garry",7), ("Ian",4), ("Neal",6), ("Wally",3), ("Emma",4)]),
("The Green Mile","Frank Darabont",1999,[("Sam",3), ("Zoe",4), ("Dave",8), ("Wally",5), ("Jo",5)]),
("True Lies","James Cameron",1994,[("Dave",3), ("Kevin",4), ("Jo",0)]),
("Minority Report","Steven Spielberg",2002,[("Dave",5), ("Garry",6), ("Megan",2), ("Sam",7), ("Wally",8)]),
("The Wolf of Wall Street","Martin Scorsese",2013,[("Dave",6), ("Garry",6), ("Megan",0), ("Sam",4)]),
("War Horse","Steven Spielberg",2011,[("Dave",6), ("Garry",6), ("Megan",3), ("Sam",7), ("Wally",8), ("Zoe",8)]),
("Lincoln","Steven Spielberg",2012,[("Ian",3), ("Sam",7), ("Wally",3), ("Zoe",4), ("Liz",7), ("Megan",4)]),
("Vertigo","Alfred Hitchcock",1958,[("Bill",7), ("Emma",5), ("Zoe",9), ("Olga",6), ("Tim",10)]),
("The Terminal","Steven Spielberg",2004,[("Olga",3), ("Heidi",8), ("Bill",2), ("Sam",6), ("Garry",8)]),
("Jaws","Steven Spielberg",1975,[("Fred",3), ("Garry",0), ("Jo",3), ("Neal",9), ("Emma",7)]),
("Hugo","Martin Scorsese",2011,[("Sam",4), ("Wally",3), ("Zoe",4), ("Liz",7)])]
```

And I am reading this file like this :

```
input2 <- readFile "C:/Users/Alex/Dropbox/Uni Work Year 2/Year 2/MATHFUN/testData.txt"
let testDatabase = input2
```

Now, i have another function that is being called within the IO, called addFilms, which has arguments String, String, Int and [Film]. [Film] is the definition for my database.

However when i try to call the fucntion i get this error:

```
HaskellCW.hs:155:47:
Couldn't match type `Char' with `(String, String, Int, [Rating])'
Expected type: [Film]
  Actual type: String
In the fourth argument of `addFilm', namely `testDatabase'
In the first argument of `putStrLn', namely
  `(addFilm title director year testDatabase)'
In a stmt of a 'do' block:
  putStrLn (addFilm title director year testDatabase)
```

Can anyone help me with this at all? I need to keep the database as type [Film]. Find below the code i have.

```
type Film   = (String, String, Int, [Rating])

testDatabase :: [Film]

addFilm :: String -> String -> Int -> [Film] -> String
addFilm nTitle nDirector nYear films    | [nTitle] == title = show films
                                    | otherwise         = show (films ++ [newfilm])
                                 where   newfilm        = (nTitle, nDirector, nYear, ratings)
                                         title          = [title | (title,director,year,ratings) <- films]
                                         ratings        = []

main :: IO ()
main = do
putStrLn "Please Enter Your Name: "
input <- getLine
let userName = input
putStrLn ("Your name is: " ++ userName)
input2 <- readFile "C:/Users/Alex/Dropbox/Uni Work Year 2/Year 2/MATHFUN/testData.txt"
let testDatabase = input2
putStrLn testDatabase

putStrLn "Type a function to perform. List of Functions: "
putStrLn "addFilm, showFilms, getDirector, getHighRatings, getAverageDirector, getUserRatings"

str <- getLine
if  str == "addFilm" then do
    putStrLn "Function addFilm"
    putStrLn "Enter film title: "
    input1 <- getLine
    let title = input1
    putStrLn "Enter film director: "
    input2 <- getLine
    let director = input2
    putStrLn "Enter film year: "
    input3 <- getLine
    let year = (read input3 :: Int)
    putStrLn (addFilm title director year testDatabase)
else if str == "showFilms" then do
    putStrLn "Function showFilms"
else if str == "getDirector" then do
    putStrLn "Function getDirector"
else if str == "getHighRatings" then do
    putStrLn "Function getHighRatings"
else if str == "getAverageDirector" then do
    putStrLn "Function getAverageDirector"
else if str == "getUserRatings" then do
    putStrLn "Function getUserRatings"
else do
    putStrLn "Thankyou for using the system, saving the database."
    writeFile "C:/Users/Alex/Dropbox/Uni Work Year 2/Year 2/MATHFUN/testData.txt" testDatabase
```

Comment: Could you clean up your code a bit?  It's all over the place in `addFilm`.  If you're using tabs in your editor, you might want to consider finding the setting that replaces them by spaces.  Haskell doesn't play well with mixed tabs and spaces.

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice, will do that.

Comment: Unrelated: instead of a list of `if-else` statements, use `case`:

    case str of
      "showFilms"   -> putStrLn "Function showFilms"
      "getDirector" -> putStrLn "Function getDirector"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your string contains a string representation of your actual Haskell info: `1` is an `Int`, but `"1"` is a `String`. You can't pass a `String` to a function that accepts `[Film]`, for the same reason `5 + 4 + "6"` is not a valid expression.

Use [read](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v%3aread):

```
input2 <- readFile "C:/Users/Alex/Dropbox/Uni Work Year 2/Year 2/MATHFUN/testData.txt"
let testDatabase = read input2 :: [Film]
```

It'll parse the input and convert it to `[Film]`. `read` is essentially the opposite of `show`: It gets a string representation of an Haskell value and returns the actual value.

Note that a type signature may be crucial here. If you write `1 + read "2"` Haskell can infer from the context that `"2"` represents an `Int`, but `read "2"` alone will result in a compiler error, since `"2"` can mean several things - the number `2` and the string `"2"`, for example - and Haskell won't be able to infer its type.

You can read more about `read` and `show` [here](http://learnyouahaskell.com/types-and-typeclasses#typeclasses-101).